# Start jetty with a maven war artifact downloaded from remote repository

Tags: maven, jetty

I am trying to figgure out if it is possible to use maven to download a war artifact from a repository and start that using the jetty plugin.

The reason is that I would like one of my customers to automatically use the latest version of one of my projects, by fetching the build my CI server uploaded to my companies Maven repo.

Is this possible? If yes ... how?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know if it's possible with the jetty plugin, but it's definitely possible with the cargo plugin.

You can configure cargo to download a version of jetty and the war file you want to run. This is the configuration that I'm using to deploy to tomcat, but it shouldn't be too different from the one needed for jetty. We even use this way to deploy several wars in the same tomcat.

What I do is first download the war and tomcat (as dependencies), then use the dependency plugin to decompress the war file (this is just because I add some configuration files), and then tell cargo to start the web app from the folder where I have decompressed the war.

```
  <dependency>
     <groupId>org.apache</groupId>
     <artifactId>tomcat</artifactId>
     <version>${tomcat.version}</version>
     <type>zip</type>
  </dependency>
[...]
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-dependency-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>2.4</version>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <id>unpack war and configuration</id>
            <phase>prepare-package</phase>
            <goals>
                <goal>unpack</goal>
            </goals>
            <configuration>
                <artifactItems>
                    <artifactItem>
                        <groupId>war-group-id</groupId>
                        <artifactId>war-artifact-id</artifactId>
                        <version>version</version>
                        <type>war</type>
                        <overWrite>true</overWrite>
                        <outputDirectory>${project.build.directory}/war
                        </outputDirectory>
                    </artifactItem>
                </artifactItems>
                <includes>**/*</includes>
            </configuration>
        </execution>
    </executions>
</plugin>

<pluginManagement>
         <plugins>
            <plugin>
               <groupId>org.codehaus.cargo</groupId>
               <artifactId>cargo-maven2-plugin</artifactId>
               <configuration>

                  <container>
                     <containerId>tomcat6x</containerId>
                     <output>${project.build.directory}/logs/container.log</output>
                     <log>${project.build.directory}/logs/cargo.log</log>
                     <append>false</append>
                     <zipUrlInstaller>
                        <url>file:///${settings.localRepository}/org/apache/tomcat/${tomcat.version}/tomcat-${tomcat.version}.zip
                        </url>
                     </zipUrlInstaller>

                     <dependencies>
                        <dependency>
                           <groupId>com.oracle</groupId>
                           <artifactId>ojdbc6</artifactId>
                           <classpath>shared</classpath>
                        </dependency>
                     </dependencies>
                  </container>

                  <configuration>
                     <type>standalone</type>
                     <home>${project.build.directory}/tomcat6x</home>

                     <deployables>
                        <deployable>
                           <location>${project.build.directory}/war</location>
                           <type>war</type>
                           <properties>
                              <context>/context</context>
                           </properties>
                        </deployable>
                     </deployables>

                     <properties>
                        <cargo.servlet.port>${cargo.servlet.port}</cargo.servlet.port>
                        <cargo.rmi.port>${cargo.rmi.port}</cargo.rmi.port>
                        <cargo.tomcat.ajp.port>${cargo.tomcat.ajp.port}</cargo.tomcat.ajp.port>
                      </properties>

                  </configuration>
               </configuration>
            </plugin>
         </plugins>
      </pluginManagement>
```

Comment: Yeah ... allmost forgott about that plugin. I have to admit that I even used it for automatic integration-test-deployment. Think this will work nicely ... thanks for the pointer :-)